# Python defaultdict with string as type of value

Tags: python

Need to create a defaultdict, value type is normal Python string, it seems my below method does not work? Post compile error message. Using Python 2.7 and wondering any good ideas how to fix? Thanks.

**Code**

```
import collections

a = collections.defaultdict("")

a[1]="Hello"
a[2]="World"

print a
```

**Error Message**

```
  a = collections.defaultdict("")
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

Comment: `collections.defaultdict(str)`

Comment: @Delgan, nice! Tried "string" not working, and never though about using shorter abbrevation "str". :)

If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people. Thanks.

Comment: This is because `str` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), but `string` does not exist in Python. You can accept one of the already posted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Delgan, vote up. built-in function? I thought defaultdict requires a class other than a function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the error says, the first argument has to be a callable that produces the value you want. Use `str`:

```
a = collections.defaultdict(str)
```

If necessary, you can create a wrapper with a `lambda` function:

```
a = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 'initial')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help TigerhawkT3, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's right.  You have an instance of a string instead of something that returns a string.  What you want is `collections.defaultdict(str)`.  That is because `str()` returns `""`.  You could have found out what the type was like this:

```
>>> type("")
<class 'str'>
```

Therefore, if you didn't know the name of the class, you could have done this:

```
a = collections.defaultdict(type(""))
```

or

```
a = collections.defaultdict("".__class__)
```